# Взаимодействие двух форм через событие. WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, события, делегаты

***Здравствуйте!***

Подскажите как создать событие, чтоб оповестить главную форму о том, что в Form2 что-то произошло?

Я накопал вот такой способ:

В Program.cs записываем такое:

```
public delegate void SendMessageEventHandler(string changed, string input);
```

В Form2:

```
    public static event SendMessageEventHandler SendToPlayListFormEvent;

    public PlayListsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Пример вызова
    private void PlayListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SendToPlayListFormEvent(playList[PlayListBox.SelectedIndex][1]);
    }
```

В главную форму:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayListsForm.SendToPlayListFormEvent += PlayListsForm_SendToPlayListFormEvent;
    }

    void PlayListsForm_SendToPlayListFormEvent(string message)
    {
        // обработка message
    }
```

Это всё были примеры, что в итоге у меня:
Это Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    public delegate void SendMessageEventHandler(string changed, string input);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

А вот Form2(до главной еще не добрался):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static event SendMessageEventHandler SendMessageForUpdate;//ошибка здесь - не видит делегат
    WorkPlaceDB table = null;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table.PhoneNumberUpdate(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        Close();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table = new WorkPlaceDB();
        table.OpenConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= D:\Lenovo\Documents\Praktika OOP\Praktika\Day4\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}
```

Зачем собственно мне это нужно? 
- Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в Form2, отправленные данные для Updat`а БД были отображены в DataGridView. Тоесть мы оповещаем главную форму о том, что данные отправлены, и главная форма обновляет расположеную на ней DataGridView.

Comment: кстати насчёт моего подхода, я кое-что нашёл еще(вдруг будет полезно): для того, чтоб событие видело делегат можно написать так: public static event Program.SendMessageEventHandler SendMessageForUpdate или же объявить делегат в пространстве имён(но в первом случае всё же были ошибки с доступностю).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается совсем не так. В форме которая редактирует сущность нужно назначить кнопкам след. значения

```
//устанавливаем роли для кнопок
this.CancelButton = buttonCancel;
this.AcceptButton = buttonOK;

//кнопка ОК отдает нужный результат
buttonOK.Click += (s, e) => this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

А затем в главной форме делаем так

```
private void ButtonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var editForm = new EditForm())
        {
            editForm.Owner = this;
            editForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

            //выбранный в таблице чел
            var selectedPerson = _bsPeople.Current as Person;

            //создаем редактируемую копию
            editForm.CurrentPerson = new Person
            {
                Id = selectedPerson.Id,
                FirstName = selectedPerson.FirstName,
                LastName = selectedPerson.LastName
            };

            //отображаем форму и ждем результат
            editForm.Text = $"Редактирование {selectedPerson.FirstName} {selectedPerson.LastName}";
            if (editForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //изменяем данные в БД
                Program.Context.UpdatePerson(editForm.CurrentPerson);

                //перезагружаем данные в таблицу
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: пример работы]

Пример целиком можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExEditPerson).